# how to retrieve the column in condition in delete query

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DELETE FROM ABC
 WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT policy_no, certificate_no, renl_cert_no, eff_dt_seq_no,
      (CASE WHEN source_system_id='AP' THEN 'NA' ELSE source_system_id END )   
  FROM I_ABC
 WHERE ABC.policy_no = I_ABC.policy_no
   AND ABC.certificate_no = I_ABC.certificate_no
   AND ABC.renl_cert_no = I_ABC.renl_cert_no
   AND ABC.eff_dt_seq_no = I_ABC.eff_dt_seq_no
   AND ABC.source_system_id = ????? );
```

How can I fill those `?????` with the last column I am retrieving  from the above select statement (highlighted in bold). I am using sql server.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: gidil....i am using sql server

Answer (score 0):

Since you're just checking for a record using `EXISTS` you can just move that statement to the `WHERE` clause:

```
delete from ABC  
where exists(
    select NULL   
    from I_ABC 
    where
        ABC.policy_no=I_ABC.policy_no 
    and ABC.certificate_no=I_ABC.certificate_no 
    and ABC.renl_cert_no=I_ABC.renl_cert_no 
    and ABC.eff_dt_seq_no=I_ABC.eff_dt_seq_no 
    and (case when ABC.source_system_id='AP' then 'NA' else ABC.source_system_id end) = 
        (case when I_ABC.source_system_id='AP' then 'NA' else I_ABC.source_system_id end )   
    );
```

Comment: I think the last part of this should be simpler: and ABC.source_system_id = 
        (case when I_ABC.source_system_id='AP' then 'NA' else I_ABC.source_system_id end ). Praveen only asked how to get the CASE expression to replace the ???, not both sides of the last clause.